# Small scalar types and google protocol buffers

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

What is the reasoning behind not having small scalar types in google protocol buffers?

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar

More specifically for C++, do I transfer a `uint16_t` as two `bytes` in gpb? I'm looking into converting an existing message based protocol to gpb and this seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: Maybe because they use variable-length encoding? But there are fixed types too with 32/64 bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gbp uses variable-length encoding, meaning that the size of the transmitted integer depends on the value of the integer.
Small ints will be sent using only few bytes.
Here is a link to a guide about [gbp encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding?csw=1#varints)

In particular, if you only have one specific case of a short int (and not many of them, in which case you'll probably want to use `bytes`), you should simply cast all `uint16_t` to `uint32_t` and let varints do the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf scalar type encoding uses variable number of bytes:

- 1 byte if < 2**(8-1) = 128
- 2 bytes if < 2**(16-2) = 16384
- 3 bytes if < 2**(24-3) = 2097152
- 4 bytes if < 2**(32-4) = 268435456
  etc.

So while this may be killing you as space-savvy C coder, `uint_16t` will be taking **at most** 2 bytes only for lowest 1/4 of the range.

PB is ultimately designed for forward compatibility, and Google knows that short fixed data types will *always turn out too short* :-) (Y2K, IPv4, upcoming 2038 Unix Time, etc.) If you're really, terribly after compactness, use `bytes` as @SRLKilling recommended, at the expense of needing to write your own codec on top of it.

Comment: uint16_t may take up to 3 bytes with varint encoding, not 2 as you say.

Comment: @KentonVarda read my answer again. I said "only for lower half of the range".

Comment: @KentonVarda oh, thanks for pointing me at a mistake. It's not half but 1/4. Half it would be for signed, not unsigned.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I did not understand what you meant by "only for the lowest 1/4 of the range".

Comment: @KentonVarda wording improvement suggestion welcome :-)